# Initializing class without default constructor

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, initialization, compiler-errors

If I have a class `A` with only a copy constructor and a constructor with  parameters `int` and `int`, and I place that class inside a class `B`:

```
class B
{
public:
    B();
private
    A a;
}
```

How would I initialize `a` inside B's constructor?

I've tried `a(0, 0)`, `a = A(0, 0)`, but not surprisingly neither worked, and I receive a

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In B's constructor, you would do something like this:

```
B::B() : a(0, 0)
{
    // ctor here
}
```

Comment: that is what is said here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/, but why ?