# Explicitly initialize member which does not have a default constructor

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor

I´m trying to instantiate an object which has no default constructor so it can be referenced from any methods inside the class. I declared it in my header file, but the compiler says that the constructor for the class creating it must explicitly initialize the member, and I can´t figure out how to do that.

Really appreciate your answers, thank you in advance!

The snippet:

MyClass.h

```
include "MyOtherClass.h"

class myClass {

    private:
        MyOtherClass myObject;

    public:
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();
        void myMethod();

}
```

MyClass.cpp

```
include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass() {

   MyOtherClass myObject (60);
   myObject.doSomething();

}

MyClass::myMethod() {

    myObject.doSomething();

}
```

MyOtherClass.h

```
class MyOtherClass {

   private:
      int aNumber;

   public:
      MyOtherClass (int someNumber);
      ~MyOtherClass();
      void doSomething();
}
```

MyOtherClass.cpp

```
include "MyOtherClass.h"

MyOtherClass::MyOtherClass (int someNumber) {
   aNumber = someNumber;
}

void MyOtherClass::doSomething () {
    std::cout << aNumber;
}
```

Comment: You can create a pointer, and dynamically allocate it at the initialization site.

Comment: If you can do the initialization in the initialization list, that's your best option, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3704722/initializing-class-without-default-constructor). So it would be `MyClass::MyClass() : myObject(60) { }`

Comment: The initialization list worked, thank you very much!!!

Comment: I don't understand this *an object which has no default constructor so it can be referenced from any methods inside the class*. Can you explain your logic here? AFAIK, any member can be referenced from any other member, regardless of its construction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constructor for '' must explicitly initialize the reference member ''](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576458/constructor-for-must-explicitly-initialize-the-reference-member)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are almost there. When you create an object in C++, by default it runs the default constructor on all of its objects. You can tell the language which constructor to use by this:

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass() : myObject(60){

    myObject.doSomething();

}
```

That way it doesn't try to find the default constructor and calls which one you want.

Answer (score 21):

You need to initialize the `myObject` member in the constructor initialization list:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : myObject(60) {
   myObject.doSomething();
}
```

Before you enter the body of the constructor all member variables must be initialized. If you don't specify the member in the constructor initialization list the members will be default constructed. As `MyOtherClass` does not have a default constructor the compiler gives up.

Note that this line:

```
MyOtherClass myObject (60);
```

in your constructor is actually creating a local variable that is shadowing your `myObject` member variable. That is probably not what you intended. Some compilers allow you turn on warnings for that.

Comment: This answer has more explanation than the selected one. Upvoting

Answer (score 5):

There are **two** errors

1. Your code `MyOtherClass myObject(60);` is not initializing the member of the class, but it's instead declaring a local variable named `myObject` that will hide the member inside the constructor. To initialize a member object that doesn't have a default constructor you should use member initialization lists instead.
2. You are trying to learn C++ by experimenting with a compiler.

This second error is the most serious error and if not corrected is going to take you to a terribly painful path; the only way to learn C++ is by getting [one or two good books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/320726) and read them cover to cover. Experimenting with C++ doesn't work well for two reasons.

### First reason: C++ is complex, changing and sometimes just illogical

First, no matter how smart you are, there's no way you can guess correctly with C++, and in a sense being smart is even dangerous (because you may be tempted to skip over something "you understood already"): the reason is that it happens in quite a few places that the "correct" C++ way is indeed illogical and can only be explained as a consequence of historical evolution of the language.

In other words in many places C++ is the way it is because of its long history of evolution and not because it makes sense, and no matter how smart you are there's no way you can deduce history... history must be studied.

### Second reason: UB nasal daemons instead of run-time error angels

The second reason experimenting with C++ doesn't work well is that when you make a mistake quite often the compiler doesn't tell you you are wrong; the code simply compiles; at runtime also you're not told you're wrong, and the code simply does crazy things or may be just works for a while (it's called "Undefined Behavior").

The worst (but common) thing that can happen goes more or less like this:

1. You write WRONG code, that however compiles fine even without warnings of any kind.
2. The code also runs fine while you test it (in reality it is not running fine, but the "Undefined Behavior Daemons" just decided to produce the result you're expecting, so seems fine to you).
3. You go in production (or demo); at that point the UB daemons decided that it would be a funny moment to do things differently, and your (wrong) code makes your house explode this time.

One of the main ideas of C++ is (by default) to not do checks at runtime for logical errors; those checks would be wasted time and programmers make no mistakes (the ones they do are all caught at compile time). This approach is quite questionable (especially the last part is just wishful thinking) but this, liking it or not, is the language.

Comment: I am genuinely curious about the downvotes, any comment on why this is a bad answer would be helpful.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer, but I would suspect that some people read it in the sentiment of "Go read a book". While that is not entirely wrong, I see how someone could feel rejected.
Anyhow, the part about C++ being illogical in large parts, which makes dull study of specification details a necessity when learning the language, is sadly true.

Comment: @SuperTasche: I think that if you make the mistake the OP made it means you're just experimenting with C++ and you never read about C++ syntax for constructors (may be coming from other languages). This is in my opinion a suicidal approach to C++ (been there done that) and going to read a good book is the best suggestion I can give.

Answer (score -1):

```
MyClass::MyClass(): myObject (60){

   myObject.doSomething();

}
```

---

Initialization of the data member ends before constructor function body.in the function body you just assign